# Why java availableProcessors API keeps changing during the same run?

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, java, processors

I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()` to create my thread pool. On our own physical data center, it used to return the number of cpus being 8, and it never changed. Then every time a request (data intensive) comes in, we partition the data using the same availableProcessors API, and each thread of that thread pool processes one of those partitions.

However, recently we switch to AWS (and Docker as container), and every time a request (data intensive) comes, and wants to partition the data and so calls to that API, it returns a different number. Example:

Num Partitions Used:  [X = 12] [Y= 15] [Z = 12] [W = 5] [Q = 15] [P = 3]

This is not good. What if at the time we create the thread pool availableProcessors is 3 and when the request comes in and we partition the data it is 15.

I know that the API documentation says:

> Returns the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine.
>
> This value may change during a particular invocation of the virtual machine. Applications that are sensitive to the number of available processors should therefore occasionally poll this property and adjust their resource usage appropriately.

But my questions are

1. why it did not used to change before (always returning 8) and why it changes so drastically on AWS, and if there is a way to fix it?
2. If there is no way to fix it, how could I modify the application to make sure the thread pool and partitions are compatible?

Thanks

Comment: Re, "recently we switch to AWS." I don't know a lot about AWS, but I know it's not just a single thing. It might help you to get better answers if you are more specific about which AWS service(s) you use and how you use it/them.